# How to stop font resize of input?

Tags: formatting, fonts, input-forms

How do you stop Mathematica from resizing the input font when entering formulas with fractions and such?  When I enter a formula with a few fractions the text becomes microscopic. For example:

```
100 ((1 + tops[[i]]/100)/(1 + bottoms[[j]]/100) - 1)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You see that the 100 is at normal input text size but the fractions go tiny.  I prefer to input in the notebook in traditional notation.  This auto resizing makes it a bit painful to read.

Edmund

Comment: Related: [how-to-enter-chemical-equations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55394/how-to-enter-chemical-equations)

Comment: so use: `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ScriptSizeMultipliers -> 1]` for example.